# Can't apply css class to dynamic menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The whole project can be found here [Github](https://github.com/Mot93/MattiaRubini-com-wordpress-theme).

I added a dynamic menu on my navigation bar placed in the header. For some reason I can't figure out how to link the dynamic menu with either a class or an ID defined in my style.css file.

For some reason, neither the 'menu_class' or the 'menu_id' seem to work.

Here the menu in the header.php file:

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <!--Container of my link that are on the far right, they collapse with a small screen-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!--This code inject the dynamic menu inside thge av bar-->
        <!-- The Dynamic menu is managed in the admin section of word press-->
        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( 
                array(
                    /*must have this link to function.php
                     *In function.php we defined this menu 'alphamenu'*/
                    'theme_location' => 'top-right-menu',
                    /*this line of code removes the default menu appearence*/
                    'container'      => false,
                    /*this line makes the menu with the same layout specified above 
                     *(same as link 1 and 2)*/
                    'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
                    /*CSS class applied to the menu*/
                    'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav custom-head-foot',
                    'menu_id'        => 'custom-dynamic-menu'
                ) 
            ); 
        ?>
    </ul> <!--dynamic menu unordered list-->
</div> <!--dynamic menu div-->
```

The function.php file:

```
/*Function to register a custom menu for the admin section
 *This resurces was taken from the wordpress codex*/
function custom_theme_setup() {

    /*Registered a custom primary navigation menu*/
    register_nav_menus (
        array( 'alphamenu', __( 'Primary Menu 123') )
    );

    /*Add theme support for title tag*/
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
/*Hooking in the function "custom_theme_setup()" after the theme is setup
 *surce: wordpress plugin api hooks*/
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the render method is screwed up you can always use `.nav > div` with or without pseudo-class like `:nth-of-type(1)` or there's second way: `.nav:nth-child(1)` as query for first child inside `div.nav`?

Comment: Thank you for answering but you are much more technical that I am.
And honestly don't fully understand what you are talking about.
Sorry for my limitation.
If it might be of any help here the reference material of that function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add class, try to add it within wp_nav_menu() you wrote like this:

`wp_nav_menu( 
                array(
                    /*must have this link to function.php
                     *In function.php we defined this menu 'alphamenu'*/
                    'theme_location' => 'top-right-menu',
                    /*this line of code removes the default menu appearence*/
                    'container'      => false,
                    /*this line makes the menu with the same layout specified above 
                     *(same as link 1 and 2)*/
                    'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
                    /*CSS class applied to the menu*/
                    'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav custom-head-foot **add_your_class_within_single_quotes**',
                    'menu_id'        => 'custom-dynamic-menu'
                ) 
            );`

or you can apply selectors I wrote in first answer to your CSS.